# Как правильно выполнять серверную часть сайта?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Создаю сайт для дипломной работы, решил делать серверную часть на `php`, вернее делать запросы посредством `AJAX` на сервер, и уже ответы сервера обрабатывать на стороне клиента. 
После уже 50% созданной работы, я задумался, а правильно ли выполнять сервер таким образом, или же все таки стоит страницы переделать полностью под `php`, без `AJAX` запросов?

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите двигаться в ногу со временем, то все делаете правильно. Хороший тон web-разработки сейчас - когда front (клиентская часть) отдельно и back (серверная часть) отдельно.

Таким образом вы можете с клиента посылать запросы не только на свой сервер, но и на сторонние службы - например захотите погоду себе на сайт запилить.

Так что вы на верном пути, товарищ... Да и сейчас есть куча фреймворков, которые не составляют труда верстать нормальные красивые страницы, что на чистом php будет довольно таки не удобно.

Comment: Ну здесь вы правы, есть небольшие уже на моем этапе работы с php... Не подскажите заодно, ну вдруг если вы знаете. Каким образом можно лучше защитить свой сайт, от внедрение вредоносных скриптов и т.д.? Просто интересен данный вопрос, может даже смогу сам как-нибудь у себя реализовать.

Comment: Как вариант воспользоваться уже готовыми фреймворками для php (laravel, symphony, zend и тд). Если же хотите писать все сами, то думаю что можно посмотреть как это сделано в перечисленных фреймворках и сделать что то подобное. Ну или вот [ссылка](http://www.php.su/security/)

Comment: Большое спасибо!